# Why is this definite integral method not working?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I am trying to do the following integral:

$$I=\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}\frac{1}{a\cos^2{2x}+1}\,dx$$

I am proceeding in the following manner:
$$
\begin{align}
I &=\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}\frac{1}{a\cos^2{2x}+1}\,dx\\
&=\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}\frac{\sec^2{2x}}{a+\sec^2{2x}}\,dx\\
&=\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}\frac{\sec^2{2x}}{a+1+\tan^2{2x}}\,dx\\
&=\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}\frac{\sec^2{2x}}{({\sqrt{a+1}})^2+\tan^2{2x}}\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int^{2\pi}_{-2\pi}\frac{\sec^2{t}}{({\sqrt{a+1}})^2+\tan^2{t}}\,dt \ \ \ \ (\text{by substituting $t =2x$)}\\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int^{0}_{0}\frac{du}{({\sqrt{a+1}})^2+u^2} \ \ \ \ (\text{by substituting $u =\tan{t}$)}\\
&=0.
\end{align}
$$

But when I use some CAS and graph the function, I realise that for $a>-1$ area under the curve $y=1/({a\cos^2{2x}+1})$ remains positive. Even if I use indefinite integral of $y$, I get the same answer as you can see here:

Continuing from the last step:
$$
\begin{align}
\int{y}\,dx &= \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{du}{({\sqrt{a+1}})^2+u^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a+1}}\tan^{-1} \left( {\frac{u}{\sqrt{a+1}}} \right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a+1}}\tan^{-1} \left( {\frac{\tan{t}}{\sqrt{a+1}}} \right)\\
\text{or} \int{y}\,dx \
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{a+1}}\tan^{-1} \left( {\frac{\tan{2x}}{\sqrt{a+1}}} \right)
\end{align}
$$

Therefore,
$$
I = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{a+1}}\left[{\tan^{-1} \left( {\frac{\tan{2x}}{\sqrt{a+1}}} \right)}\right]_{-\pi}^{\pi} = 0.
$$

I fail to grasp what's wrong with my way.

Comment: I think the problem is that $\tan(t)$ is not continuous on the interval $(-2\pi,2\pi)$, so you can't simply substitute $u=\tan(t)$.

Comment: It might help to note that $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi \dfrac{dx}{a\cos^2(2x)+1} = 8 \int_0^{\pi/4} \dfrac{dx}{a\cos^2(2x)+1},$$owing to how $\cos$ behaves. In this new range, the $\tan$ substitution looks more reasonable.